# Azure WADPerformanceCountertable query returning all records while querying for specific interval

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-java-sdk

How to get records for specific interval from Azure WADPerformanceCounters table using Java API?

Tried following code, but its giving all records in table. It seems timestamp based filters are not working. Tried with PartitionKey, Timestamp, EventTick and TIMESTAMP column filtering but its same for all.

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
        try
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =   CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();


            CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference("WADPerformanceCountersTable");



         Long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         Date currentDate = new Date(currTime);


            Date endTime = getFormattedTimestamp(currentDate);
            System.out.println("endTime:" + endTime);

            // calculation of start Time to DB format in UTC
            long offsetInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 2;
            Date startTime = getFormattedTimestamp(new Date(currentDate
                    .getTime()
                    - offsetInMilliseconds));

            System.out.println("startTime:" + startTime);

            long startPartitionKey = 621355968000000000L + startTime
                    .getTime() * 10000;
            long endPartitionKey = 621355968000000000L + endTime.getTime() * 10000;



        //Query using PartitionKey
        TableQuery< PerfTableEntity > SQL = TableQuery.from(PerfTableEntity.class).where(
                "PartitionKey ge '0" + startPartitionKey + "'").where(
                "PartitionKey le '0" + endPartitionKey + "'").where(
                "DeploymentId eq '<deplymentid>'").where(
                "RoleInstance eq 'WebRole1_IN_0'").where(
                "CounterName eq '\\Memory\\Page Faults/sec' or CounterName eq '\\Memory\\Page Reads/sec'");



        for (PerfTableEntity pd : cloudTable.execute(SQL)) {

            System.out.println("\ncounterName = " +pd.getCounterName() + "= " + pd.getCounterValue() + "||" + pd.getTimestamp());

        }



        }catch (Exception e){
                // Output the stack trace.
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

}//main

private static Date getFormattedTimestamp(Date date) {
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String datestr = df.format(date);
        return df.parse(datestr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the values for startPartitionKey and endPartitionKey?

Comment: @Gaurav   startPartitionKey = 636088504373440000
endPartitionKey = 636088505573440000     appending '0' before it in query.

Comment: You should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using stringBuilder to append 0 to PartitionKey resolved the issue.